# Sublime Text 2 css browse file

Tags: css, sublimetext2

I'm using Sublime Text 2 and I want to know if there is a way into css when I write something like this:

```
#id{
    background:url(
}
```

When I write url I would know if is possible that open browse file and I select the file that I want and put into my url string (like Dreamweaver).
Is there a way to do this? Because know I have to write manually path, but I think is very useful that browse file when I write"url".

I hope there is a plugin or a package.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest to what you demand seems to be a filesystem autocompletion plugin.

See: https://github.com/lingo/sublime-fscompletion

Comment: yeah I have seen CTRL + space but not work I don't know if the problem is that I'm using Mac, I have tried with command+space

Comment: Ah seems like there is an issue currently: https://github.com/lingo/sublime-fscompletion/issues/4

Comment: A lot of people seem to use this plugin I wrote, but I have hardly any feedback in the issues.   I *think* this issue is solved.  Let me know if not!